# Why are Coulomb forces on two charges the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, momentum, coulombs-law

I wanted to explain to a person knowing some very very basics of physics, why the force of attraction on two charges $Q_1=3nC$ and $Q_2=-1nC$ are the same. Of course my interlocutor thought that $3nC$ charges should experience larger attraction force.

Well, how can you explain that to somebody that didn't fully conceptualise Newton's Third Law? Forces come in pairs - ok great - if one accepts that, the work would be over.

Or is it a strict logical consequence of Newton's Third Law and there is no other way?

I am really puzzled by this, the obvious things are the most difficult ones :)

How would you explain the situation between the two charges I mentioned? I found that textbooks give the fact about forces being the same as obvious.

Answer (score 11):

### Simple, partial answer

One way to explain this is that there are two contributions to the force, that get multiplied together. A way to express this is:
$$
F = q E
$$
where $q$ is the charge that the force acts on, and $E$ is the (magnitude of the) electric field at the location of that charge.

For the larger charge, it is true that the $q$ factor is larger, which would increase the force. However, the electric field it experiences was generated by the *weaker charge*. Therefore, the factor of $E$ is smaller for the larger charge than for the smaller charge.

Meanwhile, for the smaller charge, the $q$ factor is smaller, but the factor of $E$ is larger because it is being generated by the larger charge.

This is sort of a canonical example of something that happens frequently in physics. The strength of the interaction between two particles is determined by the charges of both particles; the first charge sources a field, and the second charge couples to that field and its motion is affected. The magnitude of the charge affects its ability to "create" a field in the same way that it affects its ability to "experience" the field, and you are sort of seeing that play out when you compute the force on both particles.

### One step further

To see that the forces exactly balance out, you need to go one step further and use the formula for the electric field of a point charge
$$
E = \frac{k Q}{r^2}
$$
Since the distance $r$ between the charges is the same, and $k$ is a constant, the only part of $E$ that changes is the charge $Q$ that generates the field. So $E\propto Q$, the charge generating the field.

Putting it together, the force is proportional to
$$
F \propto qQ
$$
From this expression, it is clear that *both* charges enter symmetrically into the magnitude of the force, so the force cannot depend on whether we are talking about the larger or smaller charge (in this setup).

Comment: I like the general approach here, but would drop E from the initial discussion and just write the forces in terms of charge, i.e. $F_{ij} = \frac{q_iq_j}{r^2_{ij}}$. Swapping i and j then clearly makes no difference to the overall product and $F_{ij}$ = the force of i on j = the force of j on i.

Comment: @SarahMesser That's fair and another totally valid way to write the answer :) I kind of wanted to emphasize the (at this level) vague idea that there's two "steps" -- a charge *generating* a field, and a charge *responding* to a field -- that both involve a charge. That idea generalizes nicely to more advanced methods, whereas the Coulomb force law is kind of specific to electrostatics. Although, I did essentially write down that $F_{ij}\propto q_i q_j$ in my last paragraph. Anyway, I think your approach would make a nice complementary answer, I am just explaining a bit why I chose to use $E$.

Answer (score 5):

You can also think of it from the conservation of momentum perspective. For a closed system (say, a universe with only two charges), the net momentum change has to be zero.

Therefor $$dP = P_{\rm final} - P_{\rm initial} = 0$$

But then the net force
$$F_{\rm net} = dP/dt = 0$$

Now, if the charges exert unequal forces on each other, then the net force will not be zero and, therefore, would disrespect the conservation of momentum. The conservation of momentum needs to be respected due to the so-called [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=superspaces%20also%20exist.-,Informal%20statement%20of%20the%20theorem,values%20are%20conserved%20in%20time.).

Comment: That actually inspired me to go somewhere simpler. The centre of mass of the two particles have to be in the same place (assumming no external forces). The only way to not displace the centre of mass is to have net force zero on the system. Hence electrostatic forces have to be the same.

Comment: @LukaszSkowron,The centre of mass not moving when external force is "0" is a result of newton's second and third laws applied to system of particles,where it intrinsically already assumes that force on the two bodies is equal in magnitude,hence your reasoning is circular

Answer (score 0):

Building on / modifying the answer from @andrew, the [electrostatic force on a charged particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) $q_i$ due to a charge $q_j$ is:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F_{ij}} = k \frac{q_iq_j}{r^2_{ji}} \mathbf{\hat{r}_{ji}}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{\hat{r}_{ji}} = \hat{(\mathbf{r_i - r_j})}$ is the unit vector pointing from $j$ to $i$ and $k$ is a constant which depends on your units.  When written like this, you can clearly see that $|\mathbf{F_{ij}}| = |\mathbf{F_{ji}}|$ by the commutative property of multiplication.

It's often useful to talk about the "electric field due to charge $q_j$" rather than the force, and divide out the part which is dependent on the charge $q_i$:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E_j(r)} = k \frac{q_j}{|\mathbf{r-r_j}|^2} \mathbf{\hat{(r-r_j)}}
\end{equation}

To relate the electric field to more-intuitive concepts like force, we'll often assume the magnitude of the charge $q_j$ is much larger than a "test charge" $q_i$, i.e. the explanations will assume $|q_j| >> |q_i|$.  That way, the "test charge" $q_i$ provides minimal perturbation of the electric field and students learning about how charges move in response to each other can study the observable, intuitive *forces* rather than *fields* which they don't directly experience on a regular basis.  [But this is just a teaching tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children). The "larger" and "smaller" don't matter.

When you have an array of charges, you sum the electric fields (and forces) from each of them:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{E(r)} = k \sum_j \frac{q_j}{|\mathbf{r-r_j}|^2} \mathbf{\hat{(r-r_j)}} \\
\mathbf{F_i} = k q_i \sum_j \frac{q_j}{|\mathbf{r_i-r_j}|^2} \mathbf{\hat{(r_i-r_j)}} \\
\end{eqnarray}

If we have a bunch of identical charged particles at the same location $r_j$ (or much closer to each other than to $r_i$), we can write $Q_i = N_i q_i$ and $Q_j = N_j q_j$.  Carrying out the sum $\mathbf{F_i}$ above and additionally summing over the $q_i$ gives the total force on the bunch of charges $Q_i$:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F_{ij}} = k \frac{Q_iQ_j}{r^2_{ji}} \mathbf{\hat{r}_{ji}}
\end{equation}

This is identical to the original equation, justifying the former's use even when the "charges" are not point particles but are, say, macroscopic objects.